# from last minute of an hour to first minute of next hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a page that store a message and a user to send the message to in a db. The form has a restriction: you can't use the same user for the next 30 seconds from when you have posted the message to the db.

```
function undisable (id,time){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#'+id).prop('disabled', false);
        }, (30000-time));
}

$('#destinatario option').each(function(){
    var ds = $(this).attr('data-ts');
    var dateArray = ds.split(" ");  // split the date and time 
    var ds1 = dateArray[0].split("-"); // split each parts in date
    var ds2 = dateArray[1].split(":"); // split each parts in time
    var newDate = new Date(ds1[0], (+ds1[1] - 1), ds1[2], ds2[0], ds2[1], ds2[2]).getTime(); //parse it
    var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = currentDate - newDate;
    if(diff < 30000){
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        undisable(id,diff);
    }
});
```

Now I'd like to add a new condition: you cannot post to any user from the last minute of an hour to the first minute of the next one. So for example you cannot post from 10:59:00 to 11:01:00 (and so on for each hour of the day). 
What is the cleverest way to set the if clause to do this?
What I am trying to build is something like:

```
if(now(minutes) is between 59 and 01){ //this is the point where I get stuck at
    $('#sendbutton').prop('disabled', true); //I cannot post
}else{
    $('#sendbutton').prop('disabled', false); //I can post
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, that complicates things.  Here's the code to solve your problem.  Relies on setTimeouts to disable and enable the button, and you can edit the times you want to disable the button easily.

```js
function time_disabler()
{
    var time_disable = 59; // time in minutes to disable the button
    var time_enable = 1; // time in minutes to enable to button
    var current_mins = new Date().getMinutes(); // current time (minutes)
    var current_secs = new Date().getSeconds(); // current time (seconds)
    var total_seconds = current_mins * 60 + current_secs; // current time overall in seconds
    var last_min_secs = time_disable*60; // time in seconds to disable the button
    var first_min_secs = time_enable * 60; // time in seconds to enable the button

    
    // if in between the two times, disable button
    if((total_seconds >= last_min_secs && total_seconds < first_min_secs) || (total_seconds < first_min_secs && first_min_secs < last_min_secs))
    {
        $('#sendbutton').prop('disabled', true); //I cannot post
        var time = (total_seconds >= first_min_secs)? first_min_secs + (60*60) - total_seconds : first_min_secs - total_seconds ;

        // set time out to recall this function, which will enable it
        var t = setTimeout(function (){
            time_disabler();
        }, time * 1000 );
        
    } else { // if not between the times, disable it
        
        $('#sendbutton').prop('disabled', false); //I can post
        
        // set time out to recall this function, which will disable it
        var t = setTimeout(function(){time_disabler();}, ((last_min_secs> total_seconds ? last_min_secs : last_min_secs + 60*60) - total_seconds) * 1000 );
    }
}
time_disabler();
```

-- Old Answer --

You would just use JavaScript's getMinutes() and getSeconds():

```js
var current_mins = new Date().getMinutes();
var current_secs = new Date().getSeconds();
current_mins += current_secs/60;

if(current_mins >= 59 || current_mins <= 1)
{
    $('#sendbutton').prop('disabled', true); //I cannot post
} else {
    $('#sendbutton').prop('disabled', false); //I can post
}
```

Comment: The situation is a bit more complex. With the page loaded I should be able to post messages after the two disabled mnutes. Something like I have done for the 30 seconds for a single item.

Comment: Edited my answer to do what you want!

Comment: Thank you! :) Was looking for an hint but you gave me a full answer!